# Is VSCode still sending data when telemetry is disabled in 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As in: [Visual Studio Code still accessing internet after update and telemetry was disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451596/visual-studio-code-still-accessing-internet-after-update-and-telemetry-was-disab)

Haven't seen any topic in 2017 yet, does it mean VSCode has finally an option to disable telemetry completely?

Answer (score 0):

If you have disabled telemetry [as described here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_how-to-disable-telemetry-reporting), VS Code itself should never send any telemetry. Keep in mind that extensions may collect their own telemetry

If you still see something being sent after disabling telemetry, please [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md) right away